.net blazor new debug profile lacks .css .js why? / no css / not applied css
i have some .net blazor serverside project that use MudBlazor for FrontEnd
i neded to add new debug profile for test env.
so i did copy defauld debug profile
renamed id to httpsTest and changed env variable as on screen

i created new appsettings called appsettings.TestEnvDevelopment.json
and everything works great except css
when i run this debugTest profile i have no mudblazor / errors css as on screen

when i run nodmal profile / css is ok and everything else also
so the question is
how to handle this properly ? what i did forget ? there i need to add this ?
thanks and regards !

Add below settings in Program.cs file, it will work properly.
builder.WebHost.UseWebRoot("wwwroot");
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();

Reason
Consume content from a referenced RCL

Full Code
using BlazorApp1.Components;
using MudBlazor.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.UseWebRoot("wwwroot");
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddMudServices();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();


thx, i didnt known that ;)
